# Creating SQL Table With Statement

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to create an SQL table from Java. I'm very new to the SQL stuff so I'm not really sure about how to do everything. Right now, my code inside one of my methods is:

```
String createSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderboard " +
                "(\nName VARCHAR(50),\nScore int\n)";
results = stmt.executeQuery(createSql);
```

I already have the Connection, Statement, and ResultSet objects defined earlier as fields. My results statement ends up returning an error, saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: query does not
> return ResultSet

I have no idea how to fix this and I would appreciate it if I get help here.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table doesn't return anything, so you could just do:

```
String createSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderboard " +
                "(\nName VARCHAR(50),\nScore int\n)";
stmt.executeUpdate(createSql);
```